# Максимум считает правильно, а минимум — нет

Tags: c#

В поставленной задаче, почему-то не выводит минимальное значение, максимальное показывает, а минимального нет, подскажите пожалуйста

```
Random rnd = new Random();
Console.Write("Введите количество элементов\t");
int n = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
int[] a = new int[n];
int[] b = new int[n];
int i = 0;
double Sum1 = 0;
double Sum2 = 0;
int min1 = 0;
int max1 = 0;
int min2 = 0;
int max2 = 0;
Console.Write(" Первая строка ");
while (i <n)
{
    a[i] = rnd.Next(0, 100);
    Console.Write(" " + a[i]);
    i++;  //Вывод первой строки 

}
Console.Write("\n ");
Console.Write("Вторая строка ");
int j = 0;

while (j < n)
{
    b[j] = rnd.Next(0, 100);
    Console.Write(" " + b[j]);
    j++;  //Вывод второй строки 
}
Console.Write("\n ");
for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
{
        Sum1 += a[i]; 
}
    Console.WriteLine("\n Сумма первой строки=" + Sum1);
double x1;
x1 = Sum1 / n;
    Console.WriteLine(" Средние арифмитическое первой строки=" +x1 );

for (j = 0; j < n; j++)
{
    Sum2 += b[j];
}
Console.WriteLine(" Сумма второй строки=" + Sum2);
double x2;
x2 = Sum2 / n;
Console.WriteLine(" Средние арифмитическое второй строки=" + x2);
Console.Write("\n");

for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
{
    min1 = Math.Min(min1, a[i]);
    max1 = Math.Max(max1, a[i]);  
}

Console.WriteLine(" Минимальное первой строки: " + min1, "\n");
Console.WriteLine(" Максимальное первой строки : " + max1, "\n");

for (j = 0; j < n; j++)
{
    min2 = Math.Min(min2, b[j]);
    max2 = Math.Max(max2, b[j]);
}

Console.WriteLine(" Минимальное второй строки: " + min2, "\n");
Console.WriteLine(" Максимальное второй строки: " + max2, "\n");

double z1, z2;
z1 = (max1 - min1) / 0.25;
z2 = (max2 - min2 )/ 0.25;
Console.WriteLine(" стандарт отклонения 1: " + z1, "\n");
Console.WriteLine(" стандарт отклонения 2 : " + z2, "\n");

double m1, m2;
m1 = z1 / Math.Sqrt(n - 1);
m2 = z2 / Math.Sqrt(n - 1);
Console.WriteLine(" стандарт ошибки 1 :" + m1, "\n");
Console.WriteLine(" стандарт ошибки 2 : " + m2, "\n");

double t;
t = (x1 - x2) / Math.Sqrt((m1 * m1) + (m2 + m2));
Console.WriteLine(" Ответ Стюринга :" + t, "\n");
Console.ReadKey();
```

Comment: Это точно метод Студента, первого курса как минимум :) `Вторая страка`...

Comment: Поправьте орфографию: страка -> строка, откланения -> отклонения.

Comment: @ NewView, да ,я учусь в первом курсе)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Потому что вы присвоили min значение равное нулю и когда вы сравниваете любой положительный элемент и 0 - вы не можете обновить min:

```
for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
{
    min1 = Math.Min(min1, a[i]);
    max1 = Math.Max(max1, a[i]);
}
```

Ну вот например:

> ```
> Введите количество элементов
> Первая страка  3 65 31
> Вторая страка  53 92 23
>
> Минимальное первой строки: 0
> Максимальное первой строки : 65
> ```

Пройдите мысленным отладчиком в цикле, помня что min = 0:

- Что меньше ноль или 3? Ноль, значит минимум оставляем ноль.
- Что меньше ноль или 65? Ноль, значит минимум оставляем ноль.
- Что меньше ноль или 31? Ноль, значит минимум оставляем ноль.

С максимум подобный метод "работает", так как у вас положительные числа в массиве, а были бы все отрицательные - вы бы спрашивали, почему у вас min считается правильно, а max - нет.

Давайте обсудим как исправить.

Вам нужно и min и max устанавливать не в ноль, а в первый элемент массива. Тогда у вас начнёт сравниваться со вторым, третьим - и всё будет правильно.

Конкретные строки исправьте самостоятельно, оставляю вам в качестве домашнего задания.

---

И напоследок. У вас огромная избыточность кода, вы повторяете одни и те же конструкции. Такую портянку текста читать вам самому неудобно и понимать ещё сложнее. Навык программирования - это умение разбивать крупную задачу на мелкие блоки и не повторять одни и те же действия.

Посмотрите:

```
void Main()
{
    Random rnd = new Random();
    Console.Write("Введите количество элементов\t");
    int n = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
    Console.WriteLine();

    int[] a = this.GenerateArr(rnd, n);
    Console.Write("Первая строка: ");
    ShowArr(a);

    int[] b = this.GenerateArr(rnd, n);
    Console.Write("Вторая строка: ");
    ShowArr(b);
}

public int[] GenerateArr(Random rnd, int size)
{
    int[] result = new int[size];
    for(var i = 0; i< size; i++)
    {
        result[i] = rnd.Next(0, 100);
    }
    return result;
}

public void ShowArr(int[] arr)
{
    foreach (var element in arr)
    {
        Console.Write($" {element}");
    }
    Console.WriteLine();
}
```

Вам нет нужды дважды писать код ввод и и вывод, дважды писать поиск минимума и максимума. Напишите один раз метод и используйте его.

Вам в общем-то и два массива a и b можно было бы сделать одним двумерным массивом размером n x 2 — тогда бы ещё больше программа бы упростилась.